# Unresolved dependencies sbt-native-packager 0.4.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm trying to build a Scala project in Jenkins but I'm getting the a `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` error message for `sbt-native-packager`.

Please note the project is old and I can't update it.

- Scala **2.9.1**
- sbt **0.11.2**

**plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"              

resolvers += Resolver.url("scalasbt", new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

resolvers += Resolver.url("SBT native packager from bintray", new URL("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")          

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe" % "sbt-native-packager" % "0.4.0")                   

libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % (v+"-0.2.11"))
```

**Full Error message**

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe#sbt-native-packager;0.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe:sbt-native-packager:0.4.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.2, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn]
[error] {file:/r7/jenkins/workspace/cms-senna/project/}default-4270b0/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#sbt-native-packager;0.4.0: not found
```

How do I solve this? What is the correct resolver?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the resolver to use https and it worked:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url(
    "sbt-plugin-releases on bintray",
    new URL("https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/")
  )(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. Scala *2.9.1* and native-packager *0.4.0*. Are you using this for production?

Comment: Yes, it is in production. why the question? too old? Everyone here work in Ruby, but have this legacy project in Scala, its doesnt any change in two years.

Comment: I was just curious :) always interested in our community and the reason for certain circumstances